Axiom schema of specification specifies a unique set?
Axiom schema of Specification says:
$
\forall A\,\exists S\,\forall x\,{\big (}x\in S\iff (x\in A\wedge \varphi (x)){\big )}
$
Hence, given the set A, specifying a φ(x) leads directly to a subset S. This means that we have only one output set S for a given φ(x) and A; hence it should be unique. Then, I would argue that this uniqueness has nothing to do with the Axiom of extensionality. I mean the uniqueness of S does not result from the equality of the members of two (or more) subsets of A fulfilling φ(x); for there is only one subset of A having such a property. Am I correct?
If I was right, then, Axiom schema of Specification could be written also as:
$
\forall A\,\exists! S\,\forall x\,{\big (}x\in S\iff (x\in A\wedge \varphi (x)){\big )}
$
Am I right?
Thanks!

The uniqueness follows from Extensionality.

You say that "specifying a $\varphi(x)$ leads directly to a subset $S$".  This is correct, but it doesn't by itself show that there aren't multiple distinct subsets $S_1 \neq S_2 \neq S_3\ldots$ satisfying this condition.  The axiom just ensures that $\exists{S}$, i.e., there's at least one.  As @MauroALLEGRANZA says, the axiom of extensionality is necessary (and sufficient) to show that this $S$ is unique... it's superfluous to include the uniqueness in this axiom.

I do agree with you that uniqueness is not explicitly stated in Axiom schema of Specification. However, look how the uniqueness has to be deduced from the Axiom of Extensionality: by comparing members of two sets one by one. The two sets are identified as "equal" if they have exactly the same members. What I say is this: we don't have multiple sets here so that we utilize the Axiom of Extensionality to evaluate whether they are equal or not. We have only one set here, the set S. Specifying a φ(x) and A leads directly to the subset S following the Axiom of Specification.

@mjqxxxx: I don't understand "but it doesn't by itself show that there aren't multiple distinct subsets S1≠S2≠S3…". If "specifying a φ(x) leads directly to a subset S", then why can we have multiple subsets S1, S2, ...?

You are not right. Existence does not means uniqueness. The axiom alone does not imply that $S$ is unique because this axiom tells us nothing about what equality means in set-theory, the concept of uniqueness only makes sense after we accept the axiom of extensionality.
With "makes sense" I mean that is something that can be mathematically proved or disproved. I hope that clarifies things.
